# Shmiras eineiyim for women

Tags: women, tznius-modesty

Is there any issue for women looking at men. Are there any halochus that apply only to women and not to men?

Comment: Regarding the special mizvot, there are two that I can think of that, while women and men are both commanded in it, are given preference to women.  They are lighting the shabbat candles and taking challah. Though I believe you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Mitzva #167: bring specified offerings after childbirth. Applies only to women.

Comment: In a nutshell, if I recall correctly, Rav Moshe Feinstein says there are essentially two categories of prohibition: anything that could plausibly lead to actual, literal *gilui arayos* -- those apply to women too. The other prohibition, *venishmarta mikol davar ra*, applies only to men because it focuses on um, anatomical reactions. Getting drunk with a coworker of the opposite gender -- first category. Being in the middle of a thousand people watching a concert -- second category.

Answer (score 0):

The [sefer chasidim 614](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.614.1) writes, among his whole lengthy piece, that

> שמכל שהאיש מוזהר האשה מוזהרת
> Whatever a man is commanded in, so to a woman.

This may include shmirat eynayim, though he does explain that this does refer to familiarity in general:

> כתיב (משלי כה יז) הוקר רגלך מבית רעך הרי שני חברים ולאחד אשה נאה. מוטב שיבא לביתך ואתה הוקר רגלך מביתו. מכל מה שכתוב בשיר השירים צריך להזהר שלא ישמע קול אשה והוא הדין לאשה שלא תשמע קול איש. שמכל שהאיש מוזהר האשה מוזהרת. ודע שכל אשה שהיא הולכת לפני בית איש ומתחלה לא הרימה קולה אבל כשהולכת לפני בית איש משמעת קול הרי כוונתה לרעה. וכן האיש. ולכך כל הרגילים בזה עליהם נאמר (ישעיהו סה יג) הנה עבדי ירונו מטוב לב ואתם תצעקו מכאב לב ומשבר רוח תיילילו. ושיער באשה ערוה שנאמר (שיר השירים ד א) שערך כעדר העזים גם לא יזכה לראות שער רישיה כעמר נקי ואם נזהר מלראו' באשה יראה את הכבוד כדכתיב (ישעיהו לג יז) מלך ביופיו תחזינה עיניך. וגם אם שער ראשו יפה ואינו נזהר בו לוקה כאבשלום שנתלה בשערו ובכל דבר שאינו נזהר ילקה בגופו. ומי שנזהר מלהסתכל באשה ואינו נזה' מבגדים חמודות של נשים הרי ילקה בבגדיו ולא יראה במעש' לבושו של כבוד. לא יושיב אדם רשעים אצל צדיקים ולא צדיקים אצל רשעים כדכתיב (תהלים א א) אשרי האיש אשר לא הלך בעצ' רשעים ובדרך חטאים לא עמד ובמושב לצים לא ישב לכך לא יושיב אדם רשעים אצל צדיקים. ולא צדיקים אצל רשעים. ולא בדין ולא בעצה לא בסעודה ולא יתחבר עמהם. שהרי כתיב (דברים כב ט) לא תזרע כרמך כלאים חטה ושעורה וחרצן במפולת יד כי היין משמח ומשכר ומאבד דעת שותהו. לכן לא יתכן מי ששותה ואין בו דעת. וכתיב (הושע ד יא) זנות יין ותירוש יקח לב. ואין הסובא חושש בלחם ואינו מרגיש בגופו דכתיב (תהלים עח כה) לחם אבירים אכל איש פת שחרית מבטל דברים רעים. ורוח רעה ומוסיף חכמה וכו'. וכל מה שאמרו חכמים בפת שחרית כנגדו להפך ביין. לכך לא תזרע כרמך כלאים. לכך לא יושיב אדם שותים יין אצל טובים שנאמר (משלי כג כ) אל תהי בסובאי יין אל תהי סובא יין אין כתיב כאן אלא אל תהי בסובאי לומר לך אל תעמוד ואל תשב ביניהם. כי מה טובו ומה יופיו דגן בחורים ותירוש ינובב בתולות אל תזרע כרמך כלאים:

Comment: Where do you see that women are commanded in shmiras einayim?

Comment: @shmosel he explains the prohibitions of men toward women and says the opposite is true for women toward men.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: They're about avoiding familiarity between men and women. I don't know if gazing necessarily falls into that category.